# TOSCA API Test Automation: Unable to view request log

Tags: automation, tosca

1. I am unable to view POST Rest API log for request. Is there any way to enable log for all the request and all the response? The way we have it for postman and SoapUI
2. I am making a post request using correct Endpoint, auth and request body but every time it say 500 internal server error. I've cross checked the request detail by making the same call on Postman but using TOSCA it gives error 500 all the time. Any idea what could be the issue?